# Getting undefined value in props in STATELESS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

This is the **Product component** where i am *fetching* the data from the database.

```
class Product extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      result: [],
      errorMessage: "",
      countData: null,
      pageNumber: 1,
      limitPerPage: 10,
    };
  }

  async getData() {
    const { pageNumber, limitPerPage } = this.state;
    const response = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:80/api/getitem?pageNumber=${pageNumber}&limitPerPage=${limitPerPage}`,
      {
        responseType: "json",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    const jsonData = response.data;
    await this.setState({
      result: jsonData.result,
      countData: jsonData.countData,
    });
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getData();
  }

  handlePageChange = (page) => {
    console.log(page);
  };

  render() {
    const { result, errorMessage, countData, limitPerPage } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {/* <FormControl className="{classes.formControl}">
          <InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-simple">Limit</InputLabel>
          <Select
            native
            value="{state.age}"
            onChange={this.handleChange} // parameter handleChange(e)
            inputProps="{{  name: 'age',id: 'age-native-simple'}}"
          >
            <option aria-label="None" value="" />
            <option value={10}>10</option>
            <option value={20}>20</option>
          </Select>
        </FormControl> */}
        <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center flex-wrap">
          {result.length ? (
            result.map((result) => (
              <div key={result._id}>
                <div className="card mr-3">
                  <img
                    className="card-img-top"
                    src={result.media.standard[0].url}
                    alt="Card cap"
                  />
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <h6 className="card-title">{result.name}</h6>
                    <h6 className="card-title">{result.brand.name}</h6>
                    <h6 className="card-title">
                      {result.price.regular_price.value}
                    </h6>
                    <p className="card-text">
                      {result.classification.description_text}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          ) : (
            <div>{errorMessage}</div>
          )}
        </div>
        <Pagination
          itemsCount={countData}
          limitPerPage={limitPerPage}
          onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
        />
        {console.log(countData)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the **pagination component** where i am getting the *values in props*. But for itemCount i am getting the undefined.

```
const Pagination = (props) => {
  console.log("props:-", props);
  const { itemCount, limitPerPage } = props;
  console.log(itemCount);
  const pageCount = itemCount / limitPerPage;
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className="pagination">
        <li className="page-item">
          <a href="" className="page-link">
            1
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

I have tried various things to debug it but haven't been successful. It would be really helpful if someone could help to find out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well perhaps on you product component your passing to Pagination a prop call `itemsCount` and on your Pagination component you except a `itemCount` prop

Comment: Thankyou so much and sorry for the incovinience @Emesto :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typo. Try using "itemsCount" as a prop with an 's' in your Pagination component.

Comment: Thankyou So much and sorry for the incovinience. :) @reincore